# udev: I Need use of udev for pendrive on linux

Tags: c, linux, udev

Can anyone tell me a little example on ubuntu-linux

1. how to write udev rule for pendrive and i can experiment on my linux machine.
2. please give steps for it i am new for udev.

---

How to run a script when i will insert usb-pendrive to my system using udev ,if any one want to help please provide me what steps have to follow on ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [resource](http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/06/some-nifty-udev-rules-and-examples/) and this [tutorial](http://fabianpeter.de/in-a-nutshell/udev-rules-for-usb-drives/).

Comment: thanks for link ,best help i got,but on my ubuntu system how to run a script on inserting usb i tried much nothing happening can you help me in this.